# Unable to run Kafka Console Producer (NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Error while running kafka producer

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testing
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.utils.CommandLineUtils$.parseKeyValueArgs(Lscala/collection/Iterable;)Ljava/util/Properties;
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$ProducerConfig.<init>(ConsoleProducer.scala:245)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:35)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
```

Comment: Can please more details e.g. Kafka version, configurations etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error is usually related to mismatched versions of Kafka jars. If this is the case, resetting your `CLASSPATH` should do the trick:

```
export CLASSPATH=""
```

Comment: Well, `kafka-run-class` should be setting up the classpath itself

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you either have conflicting jars in your classpath or you have mismatched versions of kafka broker and kafka client.